# setup main url for REST service calls in $.ajaxSetup() and only service methods in subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with REST, as I know i can do it with $.soap.

I want to do something like this, is it possible? See:

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/warfile/rest-api/cmds/",
        });
```

Then subsequent calls would be like:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "setPort",
   type: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({ "port": "8431" })
});
```

Comment: Well, I hadn't. Now I did with "method: "setPort"," in the first $.ajax call after the $.ajaxSetup() and the code execution goes through the call but doesn't enter the success or error functions..

Comment: Err, no it is going into the error function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this a bit, I discovered it is possible to do this however, it is highly unadvisable as per the standards of using ajax.